# How to implement two sets of CSS Tabs on one page?

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am trying to implement two sets of CSS-only tab groups on one page. However, when I click on certain tabs in one group, other tabs become active also. Here is my code below. I want to be able to put as many css tab groups on a page.

The html

```
<div class="row">
    <article class="tabs">
        <section id="tab2" class="tab_block">
            <h2><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></h2>
            <div>
                <p>This content appears on tab 2.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="tab3" class="tab_block">
            <h2><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></h2>
            <div>
                <p>This content appears on tab 3.</p>
                <p>Some more content...</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="tab1" class="tab_block">
            <h2><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></h2>
            <div>
                <p>This content appears on tab 1.</p>
                <p>This tab is <b>last</b> in the markup so that it can be styled as active tab on page load.</p>
                <p>Some more content...</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <article class="tabs">
        <section id="tab5" class="tab_block">
            <h2><a href="#tab5">Tab 2</a></h2>
            <div>
                <p>This content appears on tab 2.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="tab6" class="tab_block">
            <h2><a href="#tab6">Tab 3</a></h2>
            <div>
                <p>This content appears on tab 3.</p>
                <p>Some more content...</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="tab4" class="tab_block">
            <h2><a href="#tab4">Tab 1</a></h2>
            <div>
                <p>This content appears on tab 1.</p>
                <p>This tab is <b>last</b> in the markup so that it can be styled as active tab on page load.</p>
                <p>Some more content...</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
</div>
```

The css

```
body {
  font: 62.5%/1.5 Georgia,serif;
  margin: 10em 0 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 256px;
}
.tabs {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 40em;
}
.tab_block {
    position: absolute;
}
    .tab_block h2 {
        background-color: #DDD;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        line-height: 2em;
        left: -1em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        top: -2.7em;
        width: 6em;
    }
    .tab_block:first-child h2 {
        left: 5.3em;
    }
    .tab_block:nth-child(2) h2 {
        left: 11.6em;
    }
        .tab_block h2 a {
            color: #000;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 100%;
        }
    .tab_block div {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: -5.4em 0 0 -2.1em;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibilty: hidden;
        width: 0;
    }
/* last in HTML markup, but visually shown first */
.tab_block:last-child {
    background: #FFF;
}
    .tab_block:last-child h2 {
        background: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
        border-bottom-color: #FFF;
        box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        left: -1.05em;
    }
    .tab_block:last-child h2:after {
        border-bottom: 4px solid #FFF;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .tab_block:last-child div {
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
        border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        padding: 1em 2em;height: auto;
        overflow: visible;
        visibilty: visible;
        width: 40em;
    }

.tab_block:target,
.tab_block:target h2 {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.tab_block:target h2 {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.tab_block:target h2:after {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #FFF;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.tab_block:target ~ .tab_block:last-child h2 {
    background: #DDD;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    left: -1em;
}
.tab_block:target ~ .tab_block:last-child h2:after {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.tab_block:target div {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 1em 2em;
    height: auto;
    visibilty: visible;
    width: 40em;
}
.tab_block:target ~ .tab_block div {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    visibilty: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
.tab_block h2 {
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

Comment: I think I understand. the problem is that only one target can be active on a page. not more than one.

Comment: Would a sass mixin solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `:target` selector, use `:checked` selector and wrap your `section` elements in label of radio elements.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x723ffs8/7/) (***Updated example***)

Doing like this, you can have as many individual groups as possible and also without using javascript.

**HTML Structure**

```
-- row
     -- tabs
        -- input (same group)
        -- label
            -- section
        -- input (same group)
        -- label
            -- section
        -- input (same group)
        -- label
            -- section
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    font: 62.5%/1.5 Georgia, serif;
    margin: 10em 0 0;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.clear-float {
    clear: both;
}
.tab_block ~ .tab_block h2 {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}
.tab_block ~ .tab_block ~ .tab_block h2 {
    left: auto;
    right: 0px;
    transform: translate(0%, -100%);
}
.row {
    width: 40em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5em;
}
.tab_block div {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 1em 2em;
    width: 40em;
}
.tab_block h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    background-color: #DDD;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 6em;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.tab_block:last-child div {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 1em 2em;
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    visibilty: visible;
    width: 40em;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label h2 {
    background-color: white;
}
:checked + label div {
    display: block;
}
```